# Using the %timeit command to time an entire IPython notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, timeit

I am aware of using the magic command `%timeit` in an IPython notebook to time individual functions.

However, I currently need to supply the time required to execute the calculations of an entire IPython notebook. How can I do this?

One option would be to save the IPython notebook as a Python file with extension `.py` and then run the entire time feature in the command line.

However, I am dealing with several calls of the `matplotlib` functions and `pylab`. This make take so long there are runtime errors.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. Export the notebook as `*.py` file.
2. Create a new notebook.
3. Copy the whole content of the `*.py` file into **one** cell of this notebook.
4. Time this cell with `%%timeit` (note the double `%`) by adding this command
   in the first line.

You might need to edit the cell content as magic `%` commands are commented out. Likely that you don't want to measure the time for invoking things like `%matplotlib inline`. Therefore, moving these magic commands into a separate cell seems sensible.

Comment: there may be an easier way using `runipy` - but I am not sure if it's already fully compatible with ipython-4.x

Comment: @cel `runipy` looks interesting. Timing `notebook_instance.run_notebook()` might time all sorts of internal setup code in addition to the algorithms in the notebook. Does it provide explicit timing support?

Comment: I don't think so, I guess the results are only accurate if the overhead of `runipy` is small compared to the notebook execution size.